# How to add a project to Gradle settings programmatically

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to include a project for my `settings.gradle` programmatically.

This is what I tried.

```
def testArray = ["A", "B", "C"] as String[]
Settings.include(testArray)
```

But this gives me below error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.include() 
  is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[A, B, C]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried many ways[1] to define an array, but every time it is taken as a list. :(

[1] http://grails.asia/groovy-array-manipulation-examples

Answer (score 2):

`Settings` does not have an `include` method that accepts a `String[]` array.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html

You need to translate/convert the array into `varargs` using the [`*` spread operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator):

```
def testArray = ["A", "B", "C"] as String[]
include(*testArray)
```